# Exclude a few sites from tenant-wide spfx extension deployment

Tags: spfx-extensions

What's the best way to prevent/exclude a few modern sites from getting a tenant-wide extension deployment like a [global footer](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-solutions/tree/master/solutions/global-footer)?